# Resize image(Bitmap) as per aspect ratio without loosing quality of image android?

Tags: android, image

Need to resize a image(bitmap) without losing quality and clearness as per aspect ratio. I see that some time lose quality and some time lose size. I want a good quality of image after resize in mayn't exactly required height and width. I have use :
    `

```
private  Bitmap scaleToActualAspectRatio(Bitmap image) {

        int maxWidth = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
                .getWidth();
        int maxHeight = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
                .getHeight();


        if (maxHeight > 0 && maxWidth > 0) {
            int width = image.getWidth();
            int height = image.getHeight();
            float ratioBitmap = (float) width / (float) height;
            float ratioMax = (float) maxWidth / (float) maxHeight;

            int finalWidth = maxWidth;
            int finalHeight = maxHeight;
            if (ratioMax > 1) {
                finalWidth = (int) ((float)maxHeight * ratioBitmap);
            } else {
                finalHeight = (int) ((float)maxWidth / ratioBitmap);
            }
            image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, finalWidth, finalHeight, true);
            return image;
        } else {
            return image;
        }`
```

Comment: you cant achieve same quality for a larger size than your original image,

Comment: yes , i want to achieve a good quality of image in may be higher size...